# How to check if two objects are of the same type in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, typeof

I want to do this in Actionscript:

```
typeof(control1) != typeof(control2)
```

to test if two objects are of the same type. This would work just fine in C#, but in Actionscript it doesnt. In fact it returns `'object'` for both `typeof()` expressions because thats the way Actionscript works.

I couldn't seem to find an alternative by looking in the debugger, or on pages that describe `typeof()` in Actionscript.

Is there a way to get the actual runtime type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way is to use `flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()`.  Additionally, you can use `flash.utils.describeType()` to get an XML document the describes more about the class.

Comment: You'd think that this would be the default behavior, but actionscript knew... better?

Comment: i believe `getQualifiedClassName` is slower than the `is` operator.  however, it also allows comparison against Strings rather than classes, which may be useful for avoiding compilation of classes you're not using (but may still be checking for as object types).

Answer (score 17):

Actionscript 3 has an **is** operator which can be used to compare objects. Consider the following code:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var myMovie:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

trace(mySprite is Sprite);
trace(myMovie is MovieClip);
trace(mySprite is MovieClip);
trace(myMovie is Sprite);
```

Which will produce the following output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

This will work for built-in classes, and classes you create yourself. The actionscript 2 equivalent of the **is** operator is **instanceof**.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the Object.prototype.constructor.

From the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html#constructor):

```
 dynamic class A {}
  trace(A.prototype.constructor);      // [class A]
  trace(A.prototype.constructor == A); // true
  var myA:A = new A();
  trace(myA.constructor == A);         // true
```

(Conveniently, this is also how to check types in javascript, which is what originally led me to this in the docs)

So, to test this out before I posted here, I tried it in an app I have, in a class called Player.  Since the prototype property is static, you can't call it using "this" but you can just skip the scope identifier and it works:

```
public function checkType():void {
    trace(prototype.constructor, prototype.constructor == Player);
    // shows [class Player] true
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you want to use this on a class that's not marked as dynamic you have to cast the instance to an object first.  Object(myA).constructor

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to get the actual runtime type?

Yes.

```js
var actualRuntimeType:Class = Object(yourInstance).constructor;
```

Some other answers already refer to `.constructor`, but you can't always directly access `.constructor` in ActionScript 3. It is only accessible on `dynamic` classes, which most classes are not. Attempting to use it on a regular class will cause a compile-time error under the default settings.

However, because every class inherits from `Object`, which is `dynamic`, we can look up their `.constructor` property just by casting an instance to `Object`.

Therefore if we are not interested in subclasses, we can confirm that two instances are of exactly the same class by simply evaluating this:

```js
Object(instanceA).constructor === Object(instanceB).constructor;
```

I learned of this from the post "[Get the class used to create an object instance in AS3](http://joshblog.net/2009/05/11/retrieve-the-class-used-to-instantiate-an-object-in-as3/)" by Josh Tynjala.

---

A even simpler alternative that also works for me is just:

```
var actualRuntimeType:Class = yourInstance["constructor"];
```

The runtime is entirely capable of giving you the `.constructor`, it's just that the compiler complains if you use that syntax. Using `["constructor"]` should produce the same bytecode, but the compiler isn't clever enough to stop you.

I included this second because it hasn't been tested anywhere except my current Flash environment, whereas several users have said that the method described above works for them.

Comment: Very neat trick, although it does not work with VectorCollection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to account for inheritance, then you might want to try something like this:

```
if (objectA is objectB.constructor || objectB is objectA.constructor)
{
    // ObjectA inherits from ObjectB or vice versa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = new Object();
Object o = new Object();

if(o.getClass().getName().endsWith(obj.getClass().getName())){
    return true;    
}else{
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you want to test whether objectA is a subtype of objectB

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

...

if (objectA is getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(objectB)))
{
    ...
}
```